# Presto integration with MSSQL

Tags: sql-server, presto, trino

I'm looking for a tutorial or something that allow me to learn  Presto step by step.

The idea is to start integrating file's and MSSQL, which is my knowledge area.
Unfortunately, since it is a relatively new area, I didn't find anything more than Facebook page  or the Presto.io page, however it is not good enough for someone that want to start knowing the big data world from scratch.

I will appreciate your help and/or orientation in this area.

Comment: Go to amazon, search for books, order by rating, buy the first two, read.

Comment: can you point me to some books? I also looked there, but nothing in Amazon, only https://prestodb.io has documentation

Comment: That's the issue with trying to be on the cutting edge :-)   I'd suggest you to post your question (also) on the [PrestoDB user group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/presto-users/mssql%7Csort:relevance/presto-users/zCN16qCqCt4/Hq9HA_4eAwAJ). From what I've read, there should not be an official MSSQL connector, and also the "file system" integration (apart from HDFS) is just limited to Presto log files. However it's not impossible that somebody has already done some work in these two areas (for example, there's an, and he's willing to share.

Comment: As an example, there is indeed an available [unofficial plugin for MSSQL](https://github.com/CHINA-JD/presto/tree/0.107-jd/presto-sqlserver) on GitHub with some reported success in the [forums](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/presto-users/RG5Cvi-b7n0)

Answer (score 3):

Presto has 2 primary use cases:

- querying data stored in a cluster (on Hadoop's HDFS) or in a cloud (e.g. Amazon S3)
- data federation, i.e. querying (and joining) data from multiple data sources (e.g. HDFS, S3, traditional RDBMS like PostgreSQL or SQL Server)

As far as SQL Server support is concerned -- Presto supports connecting to SQL Server since https://github.com/prestosql/presto/commit/072440cbb2c8df2a689c4c903dd325013eae41a0.

When it comes to querying files -- Presto uses Hive's Metastore to keep track of metadata (everything besides actually *reading* the data). Thus the files must reside on HDFS or S3 to be accessible (other cloud data stores like Azure's Blob are, AFAIK, not supported *yet*).